# Copy .frm, .MYD, .MYI files to another computer

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can I copy **.frm, .MYD, .MYI** files to another computer? I want to copy tables to another computer. I am using MYSQL Database and PHPMyAdmin. I want to restore table by copying table files to another computer.
1. If yes, what are necessary steps in-order to copy these files safely without corrupting the data?
2. What are the risk of copying these files to another computer?

Comment: Even doing a complete copy of all files includes the risk of ending up in a instable (data corruption, data loss, unexpected behaviour, ...) setup on the new host. So you always have to do a dump and import.

Comment: What are your opinions in this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25449/can-i-copy-a-mysql-database-by-copying-the-files-what-do-the-files-contain-exac

Comment: If you have the same version of mysql, the same operating system, same file system setup, and the same config setup, and you only us MyISAM, then it could work. But I also saw setups where it went wrong. Best chance to get it work is if you shut down the mysql service, disable its auto launch, reboot the system so everything is flushed. But even then I would choose a dump over a copy.

Comment: Oh thank you, I needed a second opinion about this matter

Answer (score 0):

No. If you wish to copy database to another computer make database dump and restore it on other computer. Use `mysqldump` commandline tool to make dump. Use `mysql` commandline tool to restore.  Any GUI mysql client also can make database dump and restore for you, i.e. `HeidiSQL`.

Comment: Cant I just copy the files to another database? What are the risks?

Comment: Only the tables I want to copy not the database

Comment: If you copy files, the risk depends on database engine. In best case new tables will not appear in database, in worst entire database will be broken and not usable. If you want export only few tables, use some GUI tool to dump just this tables. Restoring is the same, just before do it you must select destination database.